# Generating class file from xsd file using vs command prompt issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this following xsd file. I try to generate class using vs command line like:
command line word =  xsd test.xsd /c

"Data at the root level is invalid. Line2, position1.".  I am not sure why I having this error. Please advise.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <ResultSet>
- <DataRow>
  <Mailing>CCACCL0030</Mailing> 
  <MailingDesc>'other response' chelsea CA</MailingDesc> 
  <Notes /> 
  <Direction>O</Direction> 
  <HistoryOnly>N</HistoryOnly> 
  </DataRow>
- <DataRow>
  <Mailing>VOUCHER20</Mailing> 
  <MailingDesc>£20 T&M Voucher</MailingDesc> 
  <Notes /> 
  <Direction>O</Direction> 
  <HistoryOnly>N</HistoryOnly> 
  </DataRow> 
- 
  </ResultSet>
```

Comment: That isn't an XSD, it's an XML instance document

Comment: Ok can I generate class from xml file ?

Comment: Your first mistake is copy/pasting XML from IE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate code:

1. Edit the example file so that the & character is encoded. Specifically, swap it for `&amp;`
2. Rename the file to test.xml
3. Run `xsd.exe test.xml` to generate a schema e.g. test.xsd
4. Run `xsd.exe /c test.xsd` to generate classes from the schema

EDIT: This worked fine for me. Here's the contents of my test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<ResultSet>
<DataRow>
<Mailing>CCACCL0030</Mailing> 
<MailingDesc>'other response' chelsea CA</MailingDesc> 
<Notes /> 
<Direction>O</Direction> 
<HistoryOnly>N</HistoryOnly> 
</DataRow>
<DataRow>
<Mailing>VOUCHER20</Mailing> 
<MailingDesc>£20 T&amp;M Voucher</MailingDesc> 
<Notes /> 
<Direction>O</Direction> 
<HistoryOnly>N</HistoryOnly> 
</DataRow> 
</ResultSet>
```

Comment: thanks for that. I tried this. xsd doesn't like having <ResultSet> tag.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me. I'll paste in the contents of my test.xml.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I have to use xsd.exe . I was using only xsd